# variable undefined in closure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, closures

I have a function like this:

```
function foo(canvas) {
    canvas.mousedown(function(e) {
        console.log(canvas); //undefined
    });
}
```

I'm calling foo on mouse click in a certain spot of the page.

Why is canvas undefined?

Comment: Did you pass `foo` a parameter?

Comment: `.mousedown` should be `.onmousedown`, no?

Comment: @SLaks you mean an argument, not parameter.

Comment: WFM: http://jsfiddle.net/3Xf7q/

Comment: sure I pass it, and the mousedown listener (canvas is a jquery element) works

Comment: hm... yes, jsfiddle works. my code is more complex, will see what else can be causing the problem...

Comment: `canvas` should *never* evaluate to undefined inside the callback. The `canvas` variable *cannot* be re-assigned in the provided code (an object being mutated is another matter), and *that particular* `console.log` would only run if `canvas.mousedown` was valid (which implies `canvas` *is not* undefined). Thus, **I call shenanigans.** The reported behavior is either wrong or is not the whole story.

Comment: @TML That actually doesn't work for me.

Comment: I'm using Chrome on windows and the jsfiddle works, I see the output in the console.

Comment: @TML and others: Works fine for me in FF. It helps to set the background color on the canvas so you can see the damn thing!

Comment: EDIT sorry guys i thought it was bound to load not mousedown.

Comment: Working fine for me in both Chrome and Firefox on Win32. What version of Chrome are you using? Did you actually click on the canvas? [SnagIt Screenshot of Chrome result](http://content.screencast.com/users/TML/folders/Snagit/media/10cf1dce-2ff4-4983-9145-0fbb611a0e1b/10.30.2012-14.16.png)

Comment: @TML yeah I brainfarted and assumed it was bound to load. Sorry.

Comment: would it be helpful to point out that you've left out a bracket after function (e)?

Comment: I came back to this and found the problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was this:

```
function foo(canvas) {
    canvas.mousedown(function(e) {
        console.log(canvas); //undefined
        //...
        for (var i in array) {
            var canvas = array[i].canvas;
            //...
        }
    });
}
```

I haven't time to investigate the exact reason. My guess is that the compiler puts a "var canvas" declaration at the start of the anonymous function, such that the variable is undefined when output in the console. Otherwise don't understand it yet.

Comment: This is a brilliant and underrated answer that reveals some hidden behavior and complexity about variable scoping. Also a situation where using `let canvas = ...` from [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) would work!

Comment: What would be the solution to this?

Answer (score 11):

The debugger may not show the variables in the closure until they are used.

Consider this example where the a variable is defined but never used:

```
(function() {
  var x = 1;
  $(function () {
    debugger; // debugger stopped here, `x` is `undefined` in Chrome and IE but `1` in Firefox
    console.log("hi");
  }
})();
```

Same code except the variable is printed out instead of the string literal:

```
(function() {
  var x = 1;
  $(function () {
    debugger; // debugger stopped here, all three browsers show `x` as `1`
    console.log(x);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

Your own answer is correct, once you gave the whole code example.  You encountered a quirk of Javascript known as "variable hoisting."  Your code is interpreted as:

```
function foo(canvas) {
    canvas.mousedown(function(e) {
        var i, canvas; //variable declarations moved to top of function scope
        console.log(canvas); //undefined
        //...
        for (i in array) {
            canvas = array[i].canvas;
            //...
        }
    });
}
```

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: Right, this it the answer and the reason of the issue! And it helped me solving it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would just like to confirm that in chrome, what Charlie said is correct. I needed to make a reference to the variable in question before I could use it within the closure, when using the debugger statement!